# Find the minimum date between two maximum dates based off unique values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

Data example.

```
date1 = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 29)
date2= seq(as.Date("2019/05/01"), by = "month", length.out = 29)

subproducts1=rep("1",29)
subproducts2=rep("2",29)

b1 <- c(rnorm(29,5))
b2 <- c(rnorm(29,5))

dfone <- data.frame("date"= c(date1,date2),
                "subproduct"= 
                  c(subproducts1,subproducts2),
                "actuals"= c(b1,b2))
```

Max Date for Subproduct 1 is May 2021 and max date for Subproduct 2 is Sept 2021.

Question: Is there a way to:

1. Find the max date for both unique subproduct and
2. Find the minimum date from the two max dates all in one step?

The final result should be May 2021 in this case and able to handle multiple subproducts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `slice_max` after grouping by 'subproduct', `pull` the `date` and get the `min`, assign it to a new object

```
library(dplyr)
dfone %>%
    group_by(subproduct) %>%
    slice_max(n = 1, order_by = date) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    pull(date) %>%
    min -> Min_date
```

-output

```
 Min_date
[1] "2021-05-01"
```

---

Another option is to `arrange` the rows and `filter` using `duplicated`

```
dfone %>%
    arrange(subproduct, desc(date)) %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(subproduct)) %>% 
    pull(date) %>%
    min
```

Comment: Is there a way to take the min date out as a variable or something, because I don't need it  as a new column. I only need it as a variable/object.

Comment: @chriswang123456 can you check the update

Comment: Will try on real code to see what happens. One moment

Answer (score 5):

This could also be done in base R. In the end I used `Reduce` so that the solution can be generalized to any number of `subproduct`s and `date`s and not just 2 values as is the case here.

```
Reduce(function(x, y) min(x, y),
       lapply(unique(dfone$subproduct), \(x){
         max(dfone$date[dfone$subproduct == x])
       }))

[1] "2021-05-01"
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's neat. If I could give two best answers I would. Thanks for this.

Comment: Oh my pleasure. That's very kind of you. Other Arun and Thomas are true masters of R.

Comment: Yes they are very good. I need to get better at combining different functions together to create my solution. I underestimate/overlook the capability of Base R!!!

Comment: That's the case for me too. I had been so attracted by tidyverse that almost missed the very basic concepts in base R. But these days I'm trying to come up with base R solutions to get out of my comfort zone and among "Common Higher-Order Functions in Functional Programming Languages" like Reduce are truly amazing.

Comment: Yeah it is very cool to have such elegant solutions. I'm still in school where when we code in R, usually it's very much like line by line coding. Your solution along with Akrun's blows my mind still. Any recommendations on how to improve on this aspect of combining multiple functions together? Maybe a book/textbook?

Comment: Thank you that's very kind of you. Yeah Professeur Norman Matloff's the art of R programming is great and also Advanced R by Professeur Hadly Wickham should be read 5 times at least which you can read online in the link bellow and in the end try try try & practice as much as possible here and wherever a question comes up:
https://adv-r.hadley.nz/

Comment: Much appreciated. One day my skills will match you guys and I won't need to ask so many questions lol

Comment: Hadley's [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) is also a good start.

Comment: And also this one that is fantastic plus the one Martin mentioned:
https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/

Answer (score 4):

For your first goal, you can try `subset` + `ave` like below

```
out1 <- subset(
    dfone,
    ave(date, subproduct, FUN = max) == date
)
```

which gives

```
         date subproduct  actuals
29 2021-05-01          1 5.728420
58 2021-09-01          2 3.455491
```

---

For your second goal, based on `out1`, you can try

```
out2 <- subset(
    out1,
    date == min(date)
)
```

which gives

```
         date subproduct  actuals
29 2021-05-01          1 5.083229
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here are also [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) and [sqldf](/questions/tagged/sqldf) solutions:

#### 1. data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfone)[, max(date), by = subproduct][, min(V1)]
```

> [1] "2021-05-01"

#### 2. sqldf

```
sqldf::sqldf("
select min(date) from (
  select max(date) as date from dfone group by subproduct
)", method = "Date")
```

> ```
>    min(date)
> 1 2021-05-01
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt - sort the `dfone` data by `date` descending, find the first instance of each `subproduct`, and take the minimum:

```
with(dfone[order(dfone$date, decreasing=TRUE),], 
     min(date[match(unique(subproduct), subproduct)]))
#[1] "2021-05-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the question has been marked as solved, yet one more hack where you can use `{}` anonymous call

```r
library(dplyr)

dfone %>% group_by(subproduct) %>%
  summarise(d = max(date), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  {min(.$d)}

#> [1] "2021-05-01"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Absolute brilliance.